# Differences between Chiac and French?

Tags: dialectes

I'm aware of the existence of the Chiac dialect, but I don't know much about it.  Could someone please explain how prevalent it is, and how it differs from other French dialects?

Comment: I heard people talk Chiac in New-Brunswick but I won't even try to explain anything about it as I had hard times understanding what people where saying, while I'm fluent french and québecois ;)

Comment: @LudoMC since you're the closest, please go back there and make a full investigation, thanks!

Comment: @Joubarc I'm living in Monaco, so 6 000 kms from Chiac speaking people! I just go in QC/NB at least once a year for 20 yrs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiac). It seems to be a recent creole of French and English in use in a specific region of Canada, and totally unknown where I am.

Comment: This specific region is in the atlantic's provinces (New Brunswick, Price Edward Island and Nova Scotia)...